# nVidia 9600 GT with 2 monitors on DVI and a StarTech USB2VGAE3 adapter for 3 monitor setup

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, dvi

I have a nVidia 9600 GT (1xHDMI, 2xDVI, 1xDP) and a StarTech USB2VGAE3 adapter.

I had this setup with 2 monitors connected to the DVI ports on 9600GT and 1 to the StarTech. Worked perfectly. StarTech was for email only (this is a work PC). Ran Windows 7 and then upgraded to Windows 10 still all working fine.

I now have 3 new monitors (Dell P2417H with 1xHDMI, 1xDP, 1xVGA). Using DVI to HDMI cables, I managed to get all three displays working. Then after 5 minutes or so, one of the HDMI monitors turned off.

If I remove the StarTech USB cable, it comes back on, and if I plug it back in, goes off again.

Why does this happen when all three were working before? I even rebuilt PC, but still not working!

Comment: Why did you not connect one of those displays directly to the HDMI port on your graphics card? Did the display that turned of have any kind of message on it like "No Signal" or similar?

Comment: I did before, and the same result. Because I had it working with the DVI connections before I know that will work. No signal.

Comment: Try attaching the monitors to different ports and see if the problem follows the monitor or if it is always the same video port causing the problem. If they are "new" monitors then one of them may simply be faulty.